# api: how to get selected text from object sublime.Selection

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How to get selected text in `sublime text 3` plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class plugin_window__go_to_relative_plugin__Command(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):            
        window = self.window
        view = window.active_view()
        sel = view.sel()
        sublime.status_message("selection: "+sel)
```

My code throws error:

```
     sublime.status_message("selection: "+sel)
TypeError: Can't convert 'Selection' object to str implicitly
```

`view.sel()` returns `sublime.Selection` object. But I don't know how to get selected text from there.

This plugin must work as following:
When I call it on view...

[image: sublime text selection]

... it should set text `"dow = self.w"` to variable `sel`

When I do `str(sel)` it returns `<sublime.Selection object at 0x1047fd8d0>`

[Docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Selection) are not very clear for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My understanding of what the documentation means is this:

It sounds like the `sel()` method of a `sublime.View` object returns a `sublime.Selection` object, which is a container of regions—so you should be able to iterate over its contents (the regions it contains) or index into them using the `[]` operation.

You can get the text associated with each `sublime.Region` in a `Selection`by calling the `substr(region)` method of a `sublime.View` object. This makes sense as this editor allows there to be multiple simultaneous selections—one of its cooler features, IMHO.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

In case of single selection:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class selection_plugin__Command(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):            
        print('selection_plugin__ called')
        window = self.window
        view = window.active_view()
        sel = view.sel()

        region1 = sel[0]
        selectionText = view.substr(region1)
        print(selectionText)
```

Comment: What you seem to be ignoring is that there may be multiple regions, and therefore multiple `selectionText`s. BTW, this isn't an answer and probably ought to be added to your question instead.

Comment: Thank you anyway, you helped me much. For my task I need only first selection. If you add answer, I accept it.

Comment: Glad my comment helped -- the docs _are_ somewhat difficult to understand. Also not that, according to them, a `sublime.Selection` like the one `sel()` returns, "are kept in sorted order" which means that `sel[0]` is just the earliest region in the view -- the one nearest the top -- not the one near the current cursor or the last thing selected. I think if you look at the `Packages/Default/delete_word.py` pre-made plugin, you will be able to figure-out what the current cursor position is because that one "Deletes a word to the left or right of the cursor" so it must know where that position is

Answer (score 1):

Use it in console and then append in python
view.substr((view.sel())[0])